# Rails: How to toggle a boolean field from a view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, boolean, toggle

I have a boolean field called "saved" in my database. I want to toggle this field by clicking on a text link that changes from "Save" to "Unsave" depending on the situation, and updates my "Customer" table with 0 or 1. I imagine Javascript may be a way to go for this but I am not experienced enough (yet!) in Javascript to know how to code it.

I've rolled back the question to keep it shorter. Here is my exact code.

```
#employers controller
def save_toggle
  @matching = Matching.find(params[:id])
  if @matching.employer_stars == false
    @matching.employer_rejects = false # If saving a match, remove any existing rejection.
  end
  @matching.employer_stars = !@matching.employer_stars
  @matching.save
  render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :layout => false
end

#view home.html.erb
<%= render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => matching} %>

#partial _save_unsave_buttons.html.erb
<div id="save_buttons" class="buttonText"> #latter is just for CSS layout
  <% if @matching.employer_stars %>
    <%= link_to_remote "Unsave",
      :url => {:action => "save_toggle", :id => matching.id},
      :update => {:success => "save_buttons", :failure => "Error"} %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to_remote "Save",
      :url => {:action => "save_toggle", :id => matching.id},
      :update => {:success => "save_buttons", :failure => "Error"} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The database is working but the toggle text isn't switching. To @nathanvda: I'm really sorry for being such a pain - I want to confirm your answer but I know if I do I'll just leave this for a while then come back to it and get frustrated again! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a controller-method, which sets your `saved` attribute. In your view you can then link to this method using `link_to_remote`.

That should get you started.

--Update: after updated question:

You should create a partial that renders your save/unsave button like this, call it "_save_unsave_buttons.html.erb" :

```
<div id="save_buttons">
  <% if matching.employer_stars %>
    <%= link_to_remote "Unsave",
       :url => {:action => "save_toggle", :id => matching.id},
       :update => {:success => "save_buttons", :failure => "Error"} %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to_remote "Save",
       :url => {:action => "save_toggle", :id => matching.id},
       :update => {:success => "save_buttons", :failure => "Error"} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This partial will render you correct save-buttons, and upon update the containing div is updated/replaced by the result of your controller action.

From inside your main view, write

```
<%= render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => match } %>
```

where you want the buttons to be visible.

And inside your controller:

```
def save_toggle
  @matching = Matching.find(params[:id])
  @matching.employer_stars = !@matching.employer_stars
  @matching.save
  render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => @matching}, :layout => false
end
```

Good luck!

--Update again: so i presume you render a set of @matchings, i would change the naming between the collection and the item a bit, to prevent more confusion and accidental mistypings.

But actually this is pretty easy:

```
@matchings.each do |match|
  .. build your view here ..
  <%= render :partial => "save_unsave_buttons", :locals => {:matching => match}
end
```

and in your partial you can then use the correct `matching` everywhere.

Comment: Hi @nathanvda, thanks for the comments. I've updated my question above.

Comment: Hi @sscirrus: i have update my answer accordingly. I hope it is clearer now?

Comment: Hi @nathanvda: I'm almost there. Just a final error to get past - I needed to add :locals in calling the partial so it would recognize 'matching'. But, the toggles aren't working. See my update for more detail. I've given you a 1+ so far, and thank you.

Comment: Do you have a surrounding div, with an id, and is that id inside your `:update => "div-name-here". Otherwise it will not know where to send the rendered result.

Comment: @nathanvda: Everything seems to be in place but it just isn't changing that damn toggle! I've simplified everything and condensed it above.

Comment: @sscirrus, in your partial you test against `@matching.employer_stars`, but from the view you pass to a local named `matching` without the @! From your controller-method you should also pass the locals the keep it alike.

Comment: @nathanvda - the last line you write for the controller is now updating the form as it should... but for every single link the controller is toggling only the first element! If a user clicks the 3rd item in the view's loop (@matchings.each do |match|) the controller is rendering the save_buttons partial (with correct result) but it's rendering to the first loop and not the correct loop. I imagine, because the same partial is rendered many times, the controller isn't distinguishing between them all so it just renders the first one it finds.

Comment: Yes indeed, because it is in a loop you will have to give your div a unique name, and make sure that div is updated.

Comment: Thank you very much @nathanvda. I'll figure out how to create unique divs within a loop. You have been incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Just a notice:

Your `save_toggle` method is not RESTful. The HTTP PUT verb should be implemented idempotent (See o.a. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Examples), which means it should always do the same thing no matter how often you execute it. In your example, executing the `save_toggle` method once does not give the same result as executing it twice.

A better practice would be to make two methods, e.g.:

```
def set_employer_stars
end

def unset_employer_stars
end
```

or whatever you want to call them. Then you can also use these two different methods in the `link_to_remote` methods (because you now use `save_toggle` in both "Unsave" and "Save").

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment Van der Hoorn. I'll take it on board.